# How can I install canon pixma ip100 driver for Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, canon

I tried installing the driver by typing the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
```

The result was the following:

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:

More info: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

Then I typed:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and the result was the following:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.HDuHmOSJ0l --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv 84E550CD36EC35430A66AC5A03396E1C3F7B4A1D
gpg: requesting key 3F7B4A1D from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 3F7B4A1D: "Launchpad Misakovi" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I typed the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip100series
```

The return response was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-ip100series
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Kina

Answer (score 0):

kina. The issue is that this ppa does not have a Precise version. For whatever reason, the owner has not uploaded since last year for the Oneiric release. I will explain how to get the Oneiric version driver. I see no reason that it would not work for Precise, but I make no promises!

You already have the proper ppa added. Now you must change the distribution version. In the terminal enter `software-properties-gtk`. A menu labelled Software Sources will open (you've probably seen it before).

Left-click the "Other Software" tab. A list of all your current ppas will show up. Look through the list for "http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu precise main". Click on that to highlight it and press the "Edit..." button below.

This will open a window labelled "Edit Source". On the list of options will be "Distribution:" and it will be set to "precise". Change this to "oneiric". Click "Ok". Enter password if prompted.

When you now check the "Other Software" tab again, you should see that "oneiric" has replaced "precise" in the ppa name. Now in terminal enter:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip100series
```

Now if all goes well your driver will install. Hope this works well for you!

Comment: This won't work for amd64 ubuntu14.04. But thanks anyway)

Comment: Doesn't work for amd64 Ubuntu 16.04 either. Use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:michael-gruz/canon` to remove the added repository.

Comment: also does not work for ubuntu 20.04